# Instalar Versión especifica de composer

Tags: php, composer

Necesito instalar Composer version 2.0.8 en Windows me podrían orientar por favor

Comment: puedes encontrarlo en el siguiente [manual](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar con este comando

```
composer self-update 2.0.8
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este comando. Lee [answer]. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._